# Error on upload of my stored procedure into the database

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

What could cause the error that won't let me upload my stored procedure into the database?

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax

```
PROCEDURE `fel2`(IN diak VARCHAR(20), OUT ki int)
BEGIN
IF (SELECT AVG(g.grade)
FROM grades AS g JOIN subj AS s, the_users AS t
WHERE
t.id = g.user_id AND s.id = g.subj_id AND t.name = diak) > 5 THEN
    SET ki = 1;
    SELECT 'Atment';
ELSE
    SET ki = 0;
    SELECT 'N0';
END IF;
END
```

Comment: You're mixing your join syntaxes; 'FROM grades AS g JOIN subj AS s, the_users AS t' join the_users properly (cross join if you want to do this) and see if that solves your issue. otherwise, pop the query in SSMS and see what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (SELECT AVG(g.grade)
FROM grades AS g JOIN subj AS s, the_users AS t
WHERE
t.id = g.user_id AND s.id = g.subj_id AND t.name = diak) > 5 THEN
```

should looks like:

```
IF (SELECT AVG(g.grade)
FROM grades AS g 
JOIN subj AS s ON g.subj_id=s.id
JOIN the_users AS t ON g.user_id=t.id
WHERE t.name = diak) > 5 THEN
```